# Select rows with latest before and earliest after datetime

Tags: oracle

Suppose there is a table "Events" of types X and Y happened at some datetime. For example:

| Type | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| X | 30.05.2023 10:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 10:15 |
| X | 30.05.2023 10:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 10:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:15 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 11:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:15 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 13:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 13:15 |

I need to select rows with event Y and 2 closest rows with event X (latest before and earliest after event Y). So that it would look like this:

| Type | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| X | 30.05.2023 10:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 10:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 11:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:15 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 13:00 |

How can it be achieved in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that would work for this specific example's schema.  It fetches closest *values* rather than *rows*.  It might be possible to build on it to come up with something that meets the requirements fully, although I suspect a truly universal solution would require a different approach altogether.

Still, I hope it will be some inspiration at least.

The idea is basically to use `LAG` and `LEAD` to get, accordingly, the preceding `DateTime` and the following `DateTime` for each row (provided the corresponding types are `X`), then filter the set on `Type = 'Y'` and unpivot each tuple of (`PrevDateTime`, `DateTime`, `NextDateTime`) into a single column, producing the desired output format.

```
WITH
  PrevNextEvents AS
  (
    SELECT
      Events.*
    , LAG (CASE EventType WHEN 'X' THEN EventDateTime END)
          OVER (ORDER BY EventDateTime ASC) AS PrevDateTime
    , LEAD(CASE EventType WHEN 'X' THEN EventDateTime END)
          OVER (ORDER BY EventDateTime ASC) AS NextDateTime
    FROM
      Events
  )
SELECT
  x.*
FROM
  PrevNextEvents e
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (
    SELECT e.EventType, e.EventDateTime FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X', e.PrevDateTime FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X', e.NextDateTime FROM DUAL
  ) x
WHERE
  e.EventType = 'Y'
  AND x.EventDateTime IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  x.EventDateTime ASC
;
```

| EVENTTYPE | EVENTDATETIME |
| --- | --- |
| X | 30.05.2023 10:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 10:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 11:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 11:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:00 |
| X | 30.05.2023 12:15 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:30 |
| Y | 30.05.2023 12:45 |
| X | 30.05.2023 13:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CxCniaGz)